# aws-cli servicediscovery list-services won't filter multiple Namespace IDs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to get a list of Services from a set of Service Discovery Namespaces.  The API documentation makes it seem like this is something that can be done with the *IN* condition:

> IN: When you specify IN, specify a list of the IDs for the namespaces that you want ListServices to return a list of services for.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud-map/latest/api/API_ServiceFilter.html

But when I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
$ aws servicediscovery list-services --filters Name=NAMESPACE_ID,Values=ns-blah,ns-bleh,Condition=IN
An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the ListServices operation: Filtering by NamespaceId supports only 1 value
```

And if I try to supply only one Namespace ID with *IN* I get an error that I need more than one value :\

```
$ aws servicediscovery list-services --filters Name=NAMESPACE_ID,Values=ns-blah,Condition=IN

An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the ListServices operation: IN condition must have more than 1 value supplied.
```

Am I missing something?